# Maven depedency:go-offline command issue

Tags: java, maven, docker

I am trying to use the following command:

```
RUN mvn clean dependency:go-offline
```

and I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project wc-dao: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.whitecoats:wc-dao:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact com.whitecoats:wc-commons:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

My project folder:

```
1)wc-aws(JAR)
    -pom.xml
    -src
2)wc-admin(spring project WAR)
    -pom.xml
    -src
3)wc-dao(JAR)
    -pom.xml
    -src
-pom.xml
```

As I understand, maven is trying to look for an artifact online.
But the artifact is local java project (wc-dao) which my wc-admin(main project) is dependent on.

How to resolve this?

The Error occurred in the following environment:
Docker:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8 as maven_builder

ENV HOME=/app

RUN mkdir $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME

ADD . $HOME

RUN mvn clean dependency:go-offline

RUN mvn clean install -T 2C -DskipTests=true
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: What is the version of `wc-dao` module in `wc-dao/pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Maven misses the artifact

```
 com.whitecoats:wc-commons:jar:1.0
```

which seems to be *not* included in your project.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find artifact com.whitecoats:wc-commons:jar:1.0

You need to install `wc-commons` into local maven repository to be able to access it from another project, use:

```
mvn install -pl wc-commons
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

Don't forget to use correct version of `wc-commons` dependency: it should be the same as in `pom.xm` file of `wc-commons`.